# Form not routing to named route Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-routing

I know I am doing something very basic here but I can't seem to find the issue. My form isn't routing to its `named route.` Am I naming my `route` the wrong way?

**Form**

```
<form action="{{route('inventory.deduct', 'test')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="modal-body">
        Enter number of items to issue for:
        <input type="text" name="itemname" id="itemname" class="form-control" readonly>
        <input type="text" id="itemid" name="itemid" hidden>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('inventory/{id}/deduct', 'InventoryController@deduct')->name('inventory.deduct');
```

Comment: Can you write the error you are getting?

Comment: A mistake that often appears in routing is that 'inventory.deduct' already exists as a route in `routes/web.php`. First come, first serve. Except that 'test' isn't an integer, all looks fine. Integer or not, the route and 'test' should arrive in your controller. Unless you make use of a regex check in routes/web.php.

Comment: @AhmadKarimi I don't get any error.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey that what I was thinking. Regardless of the parameter it should enter my controller but it doesn't.

Comment: Can you post the controller code?

Answer (score 1):

Change your route parameter as follows..

```
<form action="{{route('inventory.deduct', ['id'=>$itemid])}}" method="post">

OR

<form action="{{route('inventory.deduct', $itemid)}}" method="post">
```

Both will work..

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form action="{{route('inventory.deduct', $itemid)}}" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

You change your action route because you pass the parameter in route.

**FORM**

```
 <form action="{{route('inventory.deduct',$collection->id)}}" method="post">

            @csrf
            <div class="modal-body">
                Enter number of items to issue for:
                <input type="text" name="itemname" id="itemname" class="form-control" readonly>
                <input type="text" id="itemid" name="itemid" hidden>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('inventory/{id}/deduct', 'InventoryController@deduct')
        ->name('inventory.deduct');
```

I hope this i may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `{id}` in an array as you called in web.php file. **['id'=>$itemid]** add it in your route of form because in web.php file you're expecting id so you need to pass it in form.

```
<form action="{{ route('inventory.deduct',['id'=>$itemid]) }}" method="post">
@csrf
</form>
```

**web.php** is correct.

```
Route::post('inventory/{id}/deduct', 'InventoryController@deduct')
        ->name('inventory.deduct');
```